# OpenFST Installation Error on Windows With pip

Tags: python, c++, openfst

I want to use openfst python wrapper on my python application.

When I run

```
pip install openfst
```

for Python 3.6 gave error as the following.

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\aliye\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\aliye\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /EHsc /Tppywrapfst.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pywrapfst.obj -std=c++11 -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-unused-function
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, it looks like the Visual Studio compiler is complaining about `/Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration` flag while it is trying to build the C extensions.

The easiest solution would be to download a pre-compiled version that matches your system at [their website](http://openfst.org/twiki/bin/view/Contrib/OpenFstWi)

Also, based on their site, it seems that they used Visual Studio 2013.You may be able to install and compile it using VS13.